# Search multiple criteria get multiple results

Tags: excel, vba, multiple-results

I'm trying to search a Table for multiple criteria and if I get multiple results for those criteria I want to display them.

Till now my code can search for multiple criteria but stops when it has found one result.

This is the code snippet:
`

```vb
Set rngSearch = Sheets(Temp_Bereich).Range("A:M")

Set Found = rngSearch.Find(What:=Material_A, _
                           LookIn:=xlValues, _
                           LookAt:=xlWhole, _
                           SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
                           SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
                           MatchCase:=False)
    
If Not Found Is Nothing Then
    
    Firstfound = Found.Address
    
    Do
        If Found.EntireRow.Range("B1").Value = Material_B And _
            Found.EntireRow.Range("C1").Value = Schmierzustand_AB And _
            Found.EntireRow.Range("G1").Value = Rauheit_A And _
            Found.EntireRow.Range("H1").Value = Rauheit_B And _
            Found.EntireRow.Range("D1").Value = Schmiermittel_AB Then Exit Do 'Match found
        
        Set Found = rngSearch.FindNext(After:=Found)
        If Found.Address = Firstfound Then Set Found = Nothing
        
    Loop Until Found Is Nothing
End If

If Not Found Is Nothing Then
    Application.Goto Found.EntireRow
    Haftreibwert.Value = Cells(Found.Row, 12).Value
    Gleitreibwert.Value = Cells(Found.Row, 13).Value
Else
    MsgBox "Es trifft leider nichts auf alle 6 Kriterien zu ", , "Kein Match gefunden"
End If
```

Comment: Can you post an image of your table and what are your search criteria , because I your are only showing variables.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You haven't explained what you want to do with multiple results if found, but this should be a start:

```vb
Dim allA As Range, c As Range

Set rngSearch = Sheets(Temp_Bereich).Range("A:M")

'call a function to return all of the matches
Set allA = FindAll(rngSearch) 'really searching entire range, or just one column?
    
If allA.Count = 0 Then
    MsgBox "Es trifft leider nichts auf alle 6 Kriterien zu ", , "Kein Match gefunden"
    Exit Sub
End If

For Each c In allA
    With c.EntireRow
        If .Range("B1").Value = Material_B And _
            .Range("C1").Value = Schmierzustand_AB And _
            .Range("G1").Value = Rauheit_A And _
            .Range("H1").Value = Rauheit_B And _
            .Range("D1").Value = Schmiermittel_AB Then
            
            Debug.Print "Matched on row# " & .Row
            
        End If
    End With
Next c
```

It's easier to manage the logic if you factor out the "find all matches" into a separate function.

```vb
'Find all exact matches for `val` in a supplied range and
'  return as a collection of matched cells
Public Function FindAll(rng As Range, val As String) As Collection
    Dim rv As New Collection, f As Range
    Dim addr As String
 
    Set f = rng.Find(what:=val, after:=rng.Cells(rng.Cells.Count), _
        LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
        SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:=False)
    If Not f Is Nothing Then addr = f.Address()
    Do Until f Is Nothing
        rv.Add f
        Set f = rng.FindNext(after:=f)
        If f.Address() = addr Then Exit Do
    Loop
    Set FindAll = rv
End Function
```